# MongoDB update - set field from nested field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I want to set a field to a value of a nested field

given

```
{
  "_id":"myId",
  "data":{
    "id":"asdfasdfasdf",
    "text":"Wonderful text"
  }
}
```

expected

```
{
  "_id":"myId",
  "messageId":"asdfasdfasdf",
  "data":{
    "id":"asdfasdfasdf",
    "text":"Wonderful text"
  }
}
```

Is there a possibility to do something like this?

```
db.myCollection.updateMany({},{ $set: {"messageId": "$data.id"} },false,true)
```

I am using MongoCompass -> _MongoSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible doing this using [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), added at version 4.2.

This is how you use it:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "message": "$data.id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qCB-z3SnATr)

For lesser Mongo versions you have to read the document first and then use the values for the update.

Comment: I am using mongodb:4.4.10

I tried 
db.myCollection.updateOne({},[{ $set: {"messageId": $data.id } }])

and got following error 

$data is not defined

Comment: great, so you can use this.

Comment: I tried db.myCollection.updateOne({},[{ $set: {"messageId": $data.id } }]) and got following error $data is not defined

Comment: it needs to be `"$data.id"` and not `$data.id`.